# Error while uploading the image to Azure Blob from a cordova application

Tags: c#, cordova, azure

I am trying to upload a blob from Cordova Application and I am getting 404. However, the SAS URL is valid and working fine with a C# Application.
Please find the code below:

```
var uriWithAccess = URL;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onerror = fail;
xhr.onloadend = uploadCompleted;
xhr.open("POST", uriWithAccess);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type','image/jpeg');
xhr.send(requestData);
```

Any help will be appreciated. I tried with $.ajax as well but it's also giving 404 error.

PS: The code was working perfectly fine but from last few days it started causing the issue.

Thanks,

Mohit Chhabra

Comment: Uploading blob is a `PUT` request while in your code you're doing a `POST` request. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I tried with POST as well but no luck there as well. My business logic for the application requires PUT request though.

Comment: Can you share your SAS URL. Let me try it on my end.

Comment: http://demoscan.blob.core.windows.net/camera/Test?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=46AOI3sHg7ZphZYJqKNyEZl34j4yX85nNfowtLx43Is%3D&st=2016-01-13T18%3A30%3A00Z&se=2016-08-12T18%3A30%3A00Z&sp=r

Comment: I noticed that the SAS URL you're using only has "read" permission in it (`sp=r`). In order to upload blobs, you would need `write` permission in your SAS.

Comment: I am generating multiple SAS URLs in order to test it so missed the Write permission in this one. Although, I am still facing issue with the write permission added to the URL as well. For Instance, I am using this url:
http://aisscansafe.blob.core.windows.net/scan/Image1?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=1SZgFE1pKj1T7B63JWLK4Oa3i1ya6amuFODbJuK%2FTyM%3D&st=2015-12-31T18%3A30%3A00Z&se=2017-03-31T18%3A30%3A00Z&sp=rwl

Comment: Are you trying to upload a blob named `Image1`?

Comment: blob name is Image1 in this scenario. I want to update the content of the blob every single time I make a call with my Image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured CORS ? maybe the js request is failing because execution domain is not allowed in azure storage.

```
<Cors>    
      <CorsRule>
            <AllowedOrigins>http://www.contoso.com, http://www.fabrikam.com</AllowedOrigins>
            <AllowedMethods>PUT,GET</AllowedMethods>
            <AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-abc</AllowedHeaders>
            <ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-*</ExposedHeaders>
            <MaxAgeInSeconds>200</MaxAgeInSeconds>
    </CorsRule>
<Cors>
```

To set that configuration you can use azure Storage REST API, or more easily you can run a short C# program like this:

```
private static void InitializeCors()
{
     // CORS should be enabled once at service startup
     // Given a BlobClient, download the current Service Properties 
     ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = BlobClient.GetServiceProperties();
     ServiceProperties tableServiceProperties = TableClient.GetServiceProperties();

     // Enable and Configure CORS
     ConfigureCors(blobServiceProperties);
     ConfigureCors(tableServiceProperties);
            
     // Commit the CORS changes into the Service Properties
     BlobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
     TableClient.SetServiceProperties(tableServiceProperties);
}

private static void ConfigureCors(ServiceProperties serviceProperties)
{
    serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
    serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
    {
        AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
        AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
        AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
        ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
        MaxAgeInSeconds = 1800 // 30 minutes
     });
}
```

I'm not sure about what host you should use to enable access to a mobile application, but at first you should try with all host.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
```

You can follow a detailed guide here:

### [Windows Azure Storage: Introducing CORS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Juank. CORS is already setup for the storage account but still getting the Issue. Also, AFAIK I should get CORS related errors instead of 404 in that case. Please correct me if I am wrong.